# java pass by value and memory and cpu utilization

Tags: java

Coming from a C background I have a very basic question: Does pass by value of a larger datatype like a String array invoke something like a copy constructor in java.

So would this code  result in creating duplicate list in memory by copying list in list2. 
Thus double memory and cpu utilization.

```
String[] getList() {
    String[] list = new String...
    ...
    return list;
}

String [] list2 = getList();
```

Is my assumption correct? If yes, is there an alternative like passing pointers in C.

PS: if we let garbage collector do the job of cleaning extra memory wont this be another set of cpu utilization of cycles of cleaning the memory which shouldn't have been created at first place.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no concept of pass by reference in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't double memory and CPU usage. In Java, all non-primitive types are stored as references and those references are passed by value.

So in your example, the `getList` method will construct an array on the heap and return a reference to that array. No array copy involved; just a reference copy.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you think the answer is wrong, why not explain why?

Answer (score 5):

No, the contents of the array will not be copied. A reference pointing to the array on the heap will be passed instead.

Java does not have pointers, it has references. In Java, references pointing to objects on the heap are passed as arguments and returned by methods. Arrays are objects in Java, so they are treated this way too.